# change/modify the dropdownlist text by value using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

i have dropdownlist with the values:

```
<select id="myddl" name="myddl">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Twooo</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I need to change the text `Twooo` to `Two` using the value of the dropdownlist option`(2)`. How can i do it in jquery?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$('#myddl option[value=2]').text('Two');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myDLLField = $('select[id="myddl"]');
myDLLField.find('option[value="2"]').text("Two");
```

or, in one line...

```
$('select[id="myddl"]').find('option[value="2"]').text("Two");
```